# How to understand '过中不至，太丘舍去，去后乃至' in this paragraph?

Tags: classical-chinese

I have a problem in understanding this paragraph:

陈太丘与友期行，期日中。过中不至，太丘舍去，去后乃至。 元方时年七岁，门外戏。客问元方：“尊君在不？”答曰：“待君久不至，已去。”友人便怒曰：“非人哉！与人期行，相委而去。”元方曰：“君与家君期日中。日中不至，则是无信；对子骂父，则是无礼。”友人惭，下车引之。元方入门不顾。

Comment: The complete sentence is like this : 友过中不至，太丘舍去，太丘去后友乃至. It's not uncommon in Chinese to leave out the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no training in the crypticities of Classical Chinese, so I am no kind of expert here, but, I think, in Modern Chinese this:

过中不至，太丘舍去，去后乃至。

would be:

过了中午还没到,陈太丘不再等候他而离开了,陈太丘离开后朋友才到.

Answer (score 1):

After noon, he didn't arrive yet, so Taiqiu left. After leaving, his friend arrived